# How to use different google analytics code for different pages in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics

I am already using one analytics code for my website. But now I want to separately use one more analytics code for specific pages. 
I am using Plugin named "Google Analytics" for integrating analytics code in my website.
So is there any way to implement this.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: What's the purpose of doing that? Maybe you should consider Segments instead? Check this out: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123951?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but this wont fulfill my requirements. I want completely different tracking for some set of pages.

Answer (score 1):

So you're probably referring to https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032400?hl=en correct?

In this case the plugin you're using won't help. You'll need something like Head & Footer Code plugin and insert codes manually on per post/page basis.

With that, in Tools → Head & Footer Code you'll put your global GA code, but then you can override it with a different code via post/page metabox for individual posts/pages/CPTs.

Comment: Thanks to answering. You have solved 60% of my problem. But I have a code like, `<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-1XXXX-1"></script>
   <script>
     window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
     function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
     gtag('js', new Date());
    
     gtag('config', 'UA-1XXXX-1'); `

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? It doesn't work when you use this snippet with Head & Footer Code plugin?